# new grub version - How to unset quiet booting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

I've got new version of grub from the newest linux.
Do you know how to disable quiet booting ?
Because I've got problem with my graphics card and to fix it I need recovery mode.

Comment: which distribution of linux are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**grub2 should show the menu, if SHIFT is pressed during boot.**

However, it seems that grub2 ignores this in case of some errors in its configuration (e.g. cannot load graphic mode).

Grub1 also has this behavior that it skips the menu when it does not found the background image.